# How to show fetched data in select, checkbox and radio inputs in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeIgniter and I used a form to insert records of user.Now I want to fetch those details and show in the update form(i have created insert and update form seperatly) after that user can make changes .I am able to show the input type="text" data but I don't know how to
show the values in select,radio and checkbox options for qualification, gender and work status.Please suggest me how can I do that?

here is my view-> update_user.php

```
<body>
    <?php foreach ($data as $row){ ?>
    <form style=" width:600px;" action="<?php echo base_url('main/updatedata/'.$row->user_id);?>" method="post" class="mx-auto bg-warning">
        <h2 class="text-center p-5">Please fill your details</h2>
        <table align="center" width="80%">
            
            <tr>
                <td class="input-group form-group ">First Name: </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $row->firstname; ?>" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="input-group form-group">Last Name: </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $row->lastname; ?>" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="input-group form-group">Gender:</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <p><input class="mr-2" type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked>Male</p>
                        <p class="mx-auto"><input class="mr-2" type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female</p>
                        <p><input class="mr-2" type="radio" name="gender" value="Other">Other</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="input-group form-group"> Qualification:</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" name="qualification">
                            <option>Uptu 12</option>
                            <option>Bachelors</option>
                            <option>Masters</option>
                            <option>Doctrate</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="input-group form-group">Work Status:</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check form-group">
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work" type="checkbox" value="Full-Time">Full-Time</br>
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work" type="checkbox" value="Part-Time">Part-Time</br>
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work" type="checkbox" value="Internship">Internship</br>
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work" type="checkbox" value="Others">Others</br>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="input-group form-group align-items-center">
                <td class=""><button type="submit" align="center" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button></td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

main is my controller and function getdataforupdate($user_id) is used for getting the id of person whose record i want to update.

```
/*Get Data For Update*/
    public function getdataforupdate($user_id)
    {
        $result['data'] = $this->userDataModel->getUserRecordUpdate($user_id);
        $this->load->view('update_user',$result);
    }
```

here is my modal function --->

```
//get user record for update
    public function getUserRecordUpdate($id){

        $query = $this->db->get_where('user_details', array('user_id' => $id));
        return $query->result();
        
    }
```

**EDIT 1**: this code is a part of my view page where all users information is shown.When I click on edit icon it is redirecting to getdataforupdate() function inside controller to get all the records of that user through user id then that fetched data should be shown on --view('update_user',$result).How can i show the data in select, radio and checkbox options thats my question.

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row){ ?>
                        <tr>            
                            <td><?php echo $row->user_id; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->lastname; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->qualification; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->salary_expected; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->gender; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->location; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->experience; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->work_status; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->user_views; ?></td>
                            <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('main/getdataforupdate/'.$row->user_id);?>"><i class="fas fa-edit" style="font-size:20px;color:yellow;"></i></a></td>
                            <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('main/deletedata/'.$row->user_id);?>"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="font-size:20px;color:red;"></i></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
```

**EDIT 2:** Everything is working as corrected by Abhishek Hanrao and Wai Ha Lee but I am not getting checkboxes checked.Is anything wrong in this? Please help me,I am unable to find the mistake.

```
<td class="input-group form-group">Work Status:</td>
                <td><?php $work_status = array('work' => $row->work_status);?>
                    <div class="form-check form-group">
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work[]" type="checkbox" value="Full-Time" <?php if(in_array('Full-Time', $work_status)){ echo 'checked';} ?>>Full-Time</br>
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work[]" type="checkbox" value="Part-Time" <?php if(in_array('Part-Time', $work_status)){ echo 'checked';} ?>>Part-Time</br>
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work[]" type="checkbox" value="Internship"<?php if(in_array('Internship', $work_status)){ echo 'checked';} ?>>Internship</br>
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work[]" type="checkbox" value="Others" <?php if(in_array('Others', $work_status)){ echo 'checked';} ?>>Others</br>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

Comment: Look into the using the Form Helper. I am not seeing where you are performing your form Validation which I hope you are doing. You should be reading the CI User Guide.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw i just want to show fetched data into form in which user is going to do updates.I have made seperate form for insert and edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code -

```
<body>
    <?php foreach ($data as $row){ ?>
    <form style=" width:600px;" action="<?php echo base_url('main/updatedata/'.$row->user_id);?>" method="post" class="mx-auto bg-warning">
        <h2 class="text-center p-5">Please fill your details</h2>
        <table align="center" width="80%">
            
            <tr>
                <td class="input-group form-group ">First Name: </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $row->firstname; ?>" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="input-group form-group">Last Name: </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $row->lastname; ?>" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="input-group form-group">Gender:</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <p><input class="mr-2" type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" <?php if($row->gender === "Male"){ echo 'checked'; ?>>Male</p>
                        <p class="mx-auto"><input class="mr-2" type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" <?php if($row->gender === "Female"){ echo 'checked'; ?>>Female</p>
                        <p><input class="mr-2" type="radio" name="gender" value="Other" <?php if($row->gender === "Other"){ echo 'checked'; ?>>Other</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="input-group form-group"> Qualification:</td>
                <td>
<!-- Add Value for each option -->
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" name="qualification">
                            <option value="Uptu 12" <?php if($row->qualification===
                                    "Uptu 12"){ echo "selected"; }?>>Uptu 12</option>
                            <option value="Bachelors" <?php if($row->qualification===
                                    "Bachelors"){ echo "selected"; }?> >Bachelors</option>
                            <option value="Masters" <?php if($row->qualification===
                                    "Masters"){ echo "selected"; }?> >Masters</option>
                            <option value="Doctrate" <?php if($row->qualification===
                                    "Doctrate"){ echo "selected"; }?>>Doctrate</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
<!-- This must be array -->
                <td class="input-group form-group">Work Status:</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check form-group">
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work[]" type="checkbox" value="Full-Time" <?php if(in_array('Full-Time', $row->work)){ echo 'checked';} ?>>Full-Time</br>
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work[]" type="checkbox" value="Part-Time" <?php if(in_array('Part-Time', $row->work)){ echo 'checked';} ?>>Part-Time</br>
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work[]" type="checkbox" value="Internship" <?php if(in_array('Internship', $row->work)){ echo 'checked';} ?>>Internship</br>
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="work[]" type="checkbox" value="Others" <?php if(in_array('Others', $row->work)){ echo 'checked';} ?>>Others</br>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="input-group form-group align-items-center">
                <td class=""><button type="submit" align="center" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button></td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```